# How to modify and set the post request body using servlet filter

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I want to do some encryption/decryption for both JSON request and response.For that i choosed servlet filter.But,i dont know how to modify  and set  the json request body.
Any solutions are highly appreciable.

Comment: are you using jersey or any other jax-rs implementation?

Comment: No ,i am using springBoot

Answer (score 1):

You must use wrappers:

```
private static class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private ServletInputStream input;

    public MyRequestWrapper(ServletRequest request) {
        super((HttpServletRequest)request);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            input = new InputStreamDecoder(super.getInputStream());
        }
        return input;
    }
}

private static class MyResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private ServletOutputStream output;

    public MyResponseWrapper(ServletResponse response) {
        super((HttpServletResponse)response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (output == null) {
            output = new OutputStreamEncoder(super.getOutputStream());
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (output != null) {
            output.flush();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    MyRequestWrapper req = new MyRequestWrapper(request);
    MyResponseWrapper res = new MyResponseWrapper(response);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
    res.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Maurice .For OutputStreamEncoder and InputStreamDecoder which jar i need to import.

Comment: @RathanaKumar it's the standard servlet API